# MySQL date conversion error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with MySQL and I am facing some problem while converting the date. I have a date column where data format is like `Mon, 22 Jul 2013 07:55:37 GMT` and I want to extract

```
Mon, 22 Jul 2013
```

when I am writing this code

```
SELECT DATEPART(pubdate) FROM rss.`RSS_FEED`; 
LIMIT 5;
```

But while I am running this code, I am getting this error

```
FUNCTION rss.DATEPART does not exist
```

Please help my out on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The formatting of the date is a presentation issue and therefore should be handled by your presentation layer (e.g. report, application, etc). Do answer your question more directly: `DatePart()` is not a MySQL function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function for that purposes. You can also use [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to extract only date part.

Answer (score 1):

The `DATEPART` function doesn't exist in MySQL. Try using DATE_FORMAT. For example:

`select DATE_FORMAT(pubdate,'%d/%m/%Y')`

adjusted for your needs of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you must do this in MySQL and not in your presentation layer

[`Date_Format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

as your column format is `Mon, 22 Jul 2013 07:55:37 GMT`

you can  use this:

```
   SELECT LEFT(pubdate,16) as yourDate FROM rss.`RSS_FEED`
   LIMIT 5;
```

**EXplanation :** this will select the first 16 characters from the left.

Answer (score 0):

If data field's *datatype* is *DATETIME*, following be the solution.

```
select id,mydate,date_format(mydate,'%a,%d,%b,%Y') from tbl_name
```

Symbols:

```
where
%a gives Abbreviated weekday name eg(Sun...Sat)
%d gives Day of the month in numeric eg(00...31)
%b gives Abbreviated month name eg(Jan...Dec)
%Y gives Numeric Year in four digits
```

---

As your question, if data format *"Mon, 22 Jul 2013 07:55:37 GMT"* is in string, first convert it into date format and then retrieve as your required date format.

```
SELECT 
    date_format(
        STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013 09:30:17 GMT','%M %d,%Y %h:%i:%s GMT'),
        '%a, %d, %b, %Y'
    )
;
```